# why is GHC thread extremely light weight?

Tags: multithreading, haskell

reading Simon Marlow's tutorial on `parallel programming in haskell`.

> a thread typically costs less than a hundred bytes plus the space for the stack, so the runtime supports literally millions of them, limited only by the available memory, unlike OS threads ....

I had different impression on thread costs. kernel structure used for a single thread exceeds 4MB (thread stack). 32bit process space can spawn no more than 1000 threads, not `literally millions`

I think he is referring to the part that GHC controlled, but if OS has already maintained stack for thread why would GHC need to do that again?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Haskell is using "green threads" (managed by the Haskell runtime) in addition / on top of operating system threads (you still need those to make use of multiple CPU cores).

> if OS has already maintained stack for thread why would GHC need to do that again?

Precisely for the reason you mention: An OS thread is heavy. A green thread can be very lightweight.

If you are familar with Java, this is roughly equivalent to using `Thread` versus submitting a task to an `ExecutorService` backed by a threadpool.

Comment: I mean why the OS structure can't be reused, and could you elaborate with some extra materials?

Comment: what do you mean by "reused"? The Haskell process itself is running on a (low) number of "real" threads. In each of them, the Haskell runtime schedules execution of a (potentially large) number of green threads.

Comment: A Haskell green thread does not get an OS-managed stack. Instead, the Haskell runtime assigns some memory area for its use (and it can grow and relocate). The OS is not aware of these threads at all (i.e. it does not schedule them).

Comment: @zinking GHC's runtime implements its own scheduling in user space. That's what 'green threads' implies. Why would it ever need the "OS structure" for that?

Comment: I mean like the `stack` mentioned, probably not OS structure. why GHC need to maintain stack for thread since OS is actually scheduling it. or it doesn't ?

Comment: No. The OS is *not* scheduling Haskell's green user-space threads. It does not even know about them. All it does is assign and schedule a low number of threads for the whole Haskell runtime as a unit.